# Datagrid View: Restricting user to NOT to select certain cells

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagrid view in which each  cell is boolean and when a user clicks on cell I save it as true otherwise as false.
Also, when user clicks on cell its color changes to Blue and if he re-clicks same cell its color changes to red.
I am saving these boolean values in database and later retrieving these values and filling cells.

After saving all these cells become Grey.
I want to divide my datagrid view in such a way that, cells which are filled from database (last selection from user) will become unclickable and other cells which are not filled should remain clickable.
Right now previously saved values when filled in cells, user can click it and it will change from default color to Blue (i.e selected == True). I want restrict user so that he can not select these cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by handling the `DataGridView`'s `CellStateChanged` event :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (...)
    {
        e.Cell.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is when you load cells from the database, set those cells to `ReadOnly`.  Then you just add one condition to your `CellClick` logic that does the color changing.

```
foreach (bool value in /* values loaded from the database */ )
{
  var cell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowToLoad].Cells[columnToLoad];
  cell.Value = value;
  cell.ReadOnly = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (!this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ReadOnly)
  {
    /* Your color logic. */
  }
}
```

This still allows the user to select the loaded cells, but the logic check will prevent color changes while the `ReadOnly` will prevent user value changes to the cell.